# NULLPointerException when trying to call another class

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

Any idea why am I keep getting NULL Pointer Exception even I start my project from scratch already. Where did I made a mistake?

[My Feature test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6bFw7.png)

[My User test model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFEP6.png)

[When trying to run the project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0Gi5.png)

Comment: I have read that, but it doesn't help as I don't really declare any variable here.

Comment: Post content on this page rather than links

Answer (score 0):

```
@RunWith(ThucydidesRunner.class)
public class LoginTest {
```

I think you need this minimally.

Ref: http://thucydides.info/docs/thucydides/_defining_high_level_tests_in_junit.html